# Finding a closed form expression for the recursion $S(n)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1} iS(i)$ for $n>1$

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursion

> What is a closed form expression for the sequence $S:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ such that $S(1)=1$ and $S(n)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1}iS(i)$ for $n>1$?

I don't know how to approach this problem.

Comment: Maybe note that $$S_n-S_{n-1}=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}iS_i-\sum_{i=1}^{n-2}iS_i=(n-1)S_{n-1}$$ and proceed?

Comment: Which part? The steps in my comment are rather self-explanatory, I would say. The step left to you is quite direct, and leaving it to you is a rather flimsy excuse to avoid posting a full solution, thus I find your reaction rather disquieting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule, when you have a recurrence $S(n)$ that is a summation of itself, it usually helps to try $S(n)-S(n-1)$ so you can cancel out most of the summation.

$S(n)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1}iS(i)$

$S(n)-S(n-1)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1}iS(i) - \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-2}iS(i) = (n-1)S(n-1)$

Now we are dealing with the recurrence $S(n) - S(n-1) = (n-1)S(n-1)$ which is a little easier to work with. Add $S(n-1)$ to both sides:

$S(n) = nS(n-1)$

And since $S(1) = 1$, we can see that $S(n) = n \cdot (n-1) \cdot (n-2) \cdot \cdots\cdot 2 \cdot 1 = n!$

Comment: Are there also other methods or is this the preferred one?

Comment: This is an example of a "full-history" recurrence, and the preferred method is to convert it to a "limited-history" recurrence so that a variety of other methods can be applied more easily (characteristic polynomials / roots, unrolling, recurrence trees, annihilators, pattern-spotting, generating functions, etc).

Answer (score 2):

$S(n)-S(n-1)=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}iS(i)-\sum_{i=1}^{n-2}iS(i)=(n-1)*S(n-1)$

$S(n)=nS(n-1)$

$S(n)=1*2*\ldots*n=n!$